# Yii 2: Not being able to set up Pretty Url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, yii2

I have installed Yii 2 advanced template. 
I have this in my *frontend/config/web* :

```
'components' => [
 .......
 'urlManager' => [
      'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
      'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
      'showScriptName' => false
 ],
```

In the *frontend/config/web/.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

In the Apache Alias file within *wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf* directory:

```
Alias /furni/ "D:\Dev.2014\furni/" 

<Directory "D:\Dev.2014\furni/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
        Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Tried making changes in the *httpd.conf* in Wamp apache folder, and restarted the server. Didn't work!

*mod_rewrite* is enabled. So I am here, left without an option except for "waking up the dawn and ask her why" :). Help is needed.

Comment: did you solve this? same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

When you using virtual directory or the Alias in your Apache config , you have to add

```
RewriteBase /furni/
```

in your .htaccess file